# Is this PHP code SQL vulnerable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So the variable ID is grabbed from the URL and stripped to prevent anything from coming through.

Then we have an IF statement to check if $ok is a number, if it is, it is now referenced as $id to be used in the SQL query below.

What other precautions should I be taking when coding to prevent access?

```
$ok=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim(strip_tags(strtoupper($_GET['id']))))));
if(is_numeric($ok)){$id=$ok;}
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE ID = '$id'");
<...more code here...>
```

Comment: Just save yourself a headache and use `mysqli_` or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: http://johnroach.info/2011/02/17/why-mysql_real_escape_string-isnt-enough-to-stop-sql-injection-attacks/

Comment: It's not. But you're seemingly trying to throw various conversion functions at it. Looks arbitrary and not well thought out. So yes, prepared statements. Albeit that doesn't fully absolve you from knowing what you're doing or learning about contexts.

Comment: Good answer Mario... not to mention, when used properly mysql_real_escape_string() is secure. I find it funny that the same programmers that would gripe at the "lazy" programmer that wanted to use register globals is now saying "just let PDO or mysqli do it for you."

Comment: `htmlspecialchars`, `stripslashes`, `strtoupper` and `strip_tags` are not needed here.

Answer (score 9):

A good way to protect against SQL injection is using prepared statements: 
http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

For example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

// Note the '?', it's a placeholder
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM games WHERE ID = ?"); 

// Providing an actual value for the placeholder
$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute()
```

This is save against SQL injection, since the statement is sent to the database without the unsafe data, which is then supplied in an extra step and inserted safely by the DB.

Answer (score 4):

Mysql has been deprecated and is no longer supported/maintained. Running mysql_ functions are vulnerable to attacks like SQL injection If you're used to mysql, it's an easy transition to mysqli. You can also use PDO.

The i in mysqli means "improved". It's improved because it supports several new things:

**Two interfaces:** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

1) Procedural (which you're probably used to as you're using mysql)

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
   if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

2) Object-oriented, where objects have invokeable methods and properties.

(example here... "*new*" mysqli is creating a new mysqli object. This particular object has a "connect_errno" method which it can call.)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

**Prepared Statements:** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

**Stored Procedures:** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

**Multiple Statements:** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

And several other improved features.

Comment: _running mysql is vulnerable to attacks like SQL injection_. You better change that.

Comment: @SalmanA what's wrong with that sentence?

Comment: mysql is a database server. Are you talking about mysql_* functions?

Comment: @SalmanA fixed the sentence

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to worry about SQL injections at all **use** prepared statements.

Using the mysqli API in PHP and prepared statements your code could look like the following example. Note that I'm using the procedural style. An object oriented style is also available.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// taken from your example
$id = trim(strip_tags(strtoupper($_GET['id'])));

if(!is_numeric($id)) {
    die('BAD id');
}

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT * FROM games WHERE ID =?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $id);

    /* execute query */
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $col1, $col2, ...);


   /* fetch values */
   while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
       printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2, ...);
   }

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Prepared statements keeping the query data like the `$id` in the example separate from the SQL Syntax. So data cannot be parsed as SQL Syntax. This is the preferred way.

If you want to use prepared statements with PHP and MySQL you'll have to use either the mysqli api or the PDO_MySQL api. You should change to one of them anyway as the 'good old' mysql api for PHP is deprecated and no longer developed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

If you are not binding parameters, you are open to SQL injection.

if you are building executable SQL code with untrusted data, then you are open to SQL injection.

It is not enough to use PDO or mysqli.  You still have to use bound parameters.  If you pass your `SELECT * FROM games WHERE ID = '$id'` to mysqli or PDO, you are open to SQL injection because you are building code from untrusted data.  You must use placeholders and bind parameters for that data.

Comment: Could you give an example of malicious input?

Comment: If `$id` has the value `'; DROP TABLE games; --`, then you will delete your games table.  See my site http://bobby-tables.com/ for more details, and examples on how to do parametrized queries.

Comment: The poster explicitly checks that the input is numeric before using the value.

Comment: I just now noticed that he's attempting to sanitize the data, and the example I gave probably would not get through.  However, the sanitization code `$ok=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim(strip_tags(strtoupper($_GET['id']))))));` is voodoo.  Does he have any idea what each of those does?  Why is it calling `htmlspecialchars` at all?  Or `stripslashes`?  All the more reason to use bind parameters and not worry about doing sanitization.

Answer (score 1):

The *ideal* answer is that you should use prepared statements, either from [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (preferred) or from [`mysqli_`*](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). The `mysql_` functions have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. In 2013, you should not be writing code like this.

On the off-chance that you are "stuck" with mysql_ functions (e.g., perhaps you have a huge legacy codebase and there is too much expense or risk to change from `mysql_` to `mysqli_` or PDO), then you are sort of on the right track. You don't need to use all of the functions that you are doing on the input. In fact, the following is sufficient to prevent against SQL injection attacks because I have used `mysql_real_escape_string` *and* quoted the parameter in the SQL string.

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE ID = '$id'");
```